# programing in c language finding change calculation

Tags: c

acually, its not showing proper change and total_price are come same and its come in negative, and loonies,cent has also problem.
can someone please tell me why?

```
int main()
{
    int items;
    int loonies=0;
    int cent=0;
    float hst=0.13;
    double change,tax, unit_price,purchase_price,total_price,cash_tendered;

    printf("enter the number of items:\n");
            scanf("%d",&items);
    printf("enter the unit_price:\n");
            scanf("%lf",&unit_price);
    printf("cash_tendered:\n");
            scanf("%.2lf",&cash_tendered);

    purchase_price=items*unit_price;
    tax=purchase_price*hst;
    total_price=purchase_price+tax;

    printf("price for items:%.2lf\n",purchase_price);
    printf("price for items with tax:%.2lf\n",total_price);

    change = cash_tendered - total_price;
    loonies=(int)change;
    cent=((change - loonies)*100);

    printf("change:%.2lf\n",change);
    printf("loonies:%d\n",loonies);
    printf("cent:%d\n",cent);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post sample input, expected output, and observed output.

Comment: Don't work with real numbers, you'll get rounding errors. Work with `int` in cents. Use an `int` for the tax rate too, such as `tax=purchase_price*hst/100`. Find a way to input a decimal number then convert to `int` in cents at soonest opportunity.

Comment: this is bad form:  loonies=(int)change;  you should use loonies=(int)floor(change);  tgmath.h

Comment: `scanf("%.2lf",&cash_tendered); `use warning `gcc -g -Wall a.c `
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:16:13: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat]
a.c:16:13: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the input statement

```
scanf("%.2lf",&cash_tendered);
```

which should be

```
scanf("%lf",&cash_tendered);
```

You also have mistakes in the `printf` statements using `%lf` format for `double` where it should be `%f`. Note that the format for `scanf` is not the same as the format for `printf`.

I notice too, you are mixing `float` and `double` for some reason.

After correcting these, my version gave the wrong change by 1 cent. This is probably because you are are working with real numbers which can give rounding errors. Best work in `int`. Use `int` for the tax rate too, and calculate with `tax=purchase_price*hst/100`. Find a way to input a decimal number then convert to `int` in cents at soonest opportunity.

I'll leave you to improve that detail.

Comment: Not should be, `printf()` also accepts the `"%lf"`, the `l` modifier for the `f` specifier. But it's certainly not needed.

Comment: @iharob isn't `%lf` in `printf` for `long double`?

Comment: Yes true, and thinking of it if the type of the parameter is not the expected type the behavior is undefined.

Comment: C11 draft standard, `7.21.6.1 The fprintf function, Section 7: l (ell) [...] has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier.` Also, any `float` passed to a varargs-function is converted to `double` (C11 `6.5.2.2 Function calls, Section 7`).

Comment: @EOF thank you I was aware of the second point, similar to `char` promoted to `int`.

Comment: `tax=purchase_price*hst/100` may give the wrong answer.  This will always truncate a fraction toward 0.  Most tax laws use a round to nearest value.  So it the tax was 1.7 cents, 2 cents would be applied, not 1.  This can be handled in positive `int` math with `(purchase_price*hst + 50)/100`. Other code needed for negative numbers. Tie cases are a deeper matter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Code did not have compiler warnings sufficiently enabled or   OP is using a weak compiler.  The following shows a bad and corrected format.

   ```
   // scanf("%.2lf", &cash_tendered);  // compiler showed warning
   scanf("%lf", &cash_tendered);
   ```
2. Code does not check the results of `scanf()`.  Unless the return value is checked, simple errors go unnoticed like a failed read from the line with an invalid format.  (for brevity, neither does the below code.)
3. After any calculation, like tax calculation, that may incur non-whole number results and needs to correct to the "penny" (smallest unit), value should be rounded.
4. Converting currency to whole numbers like cents should not use `int` conversion, `(int)` cast, `floor()` or `truncate()`.  Code should use `round()` first.

   ```
   // loonies=(int)change;
   // cent=((change - loonies)*100);
   long long change_cents = (long long) round(change * 100);
   int cent = change_cents % 100;
   long long loonie = change_cents / 100;
   ```

Amended code follows:

```
double round_to_nearest(double x, unsigned unit) {
  return round(x*unit)/unit;
}

int main(void) {
  int items;
  // These 2 are not money
  double hst = 0.13;  // tax rate
  double unit_price;  // price/unit
  // Keep money type on separate line
  double change, tax, purchase_price, total_price, cash_tendered;

  printf("enter the number of items:\n");
  scanf("%d", &items);

  // Note that unit price could be fractional like $1.234 each
  printf("enter the unit_price:\n");
  scanf("%lf", &unit_price);

  printf("cash_tendered:\n");
  scanf("%lf", &cash_tendered);
  // Could add check that the cash entered in not fractional money
  if (cash_tendered != round_to_nearest(cash_tendered, 100)) 
    Handle_Error();

  purchase_price = round_to_nearest(items * unit_price, 100);
  tax = round_to_nearest(purchase_price * hst, 100);
  total_price = round_to_nearest(purchase_price + tax, 100);

  printf("price for items:%.2lf\n", purchase_price);
  printf("price for items with tax:%.2lf\n", total_price);

  change = round_to_nearest(cash_tendered - total_price, 100);

  // round change to the nearest whole number of cents
  long long change_cents = (long long) round(change * 100);
  int cent = change_cents % 100;
  long long loonie = change_cents / 100;

  printf("change:%.2lf\n", change);
  printf("loonies:%lld\n", loonie);
  printf("cent:%d\n", cent);

  return 0;
}
```

Candidate simplification:

Internally use whole number of the lowest money units (e.g. cents) as 
rounding not needed with simple addition/subtraction.

OR

If decimal floating-point available, use that type as rounding not needed with simple addition/subtraction.